# jquery Returning object instead of the value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help. This code returns [object Object][object Object] in div text:

```
 var x = $(".2").text(Math.floor((Math.random() * 10))),
    z = $(".3").text(Math.floor((Math.random() * 10)));
    $(".div").text((x) + (z));
```

Comment: Please use a jsfiddle to provide a test case, and expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the other answers pointing out that `x` and `z` are objects, and you can access their text like:

```
x.text();
```

If you're trying to do addition with the values instead of concatenate them, you can use `parseInt()` or `Number()`:

```
$(".div").text(parseInt(x.text(), 10) + parseInt(z.text(), 10));
```

You mentioned the error in console about "Missing Radix Parameter", that had to do with the second parameter I had omitted. It sets the number base you want to use.

Taken from [the manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

> If radix is undefined or 0 (or absent), JavaScript assumes the
>   following:
>
> - If the input string begins with "0x" or "0X", radix is 16
>     (hexadecimal) and the remainder of the string is parsed.
> - If the input string begins with "0", radix is eight (octal) or 10 (decimal). 
>     Exactly which radix is chosen is implementation-dependent.  ECMAScript
>     5 specifies that 10 (decimal) is used, but not all browsers support
>     this yet.  **For this reason always specify a radix when using parseInt**.
> - If the input string begins with any other value, the radix is 10
>     (decimal).

I should've included it in my answer.

Comment: yes it works, but there is this error in console:
 Missing radix parameter.  $(".div").text(parseInt(x.text()) + parseInt(z.text()));

Comment: That has to do with the missing second parameter of parseInt(), I'll update my answer.

Comment: yes, it was solved and i am sorry for this mistake, as the error i mentioned was in brackets editor not console, thanks alot..

Answer (score 0):

`x` and `z` are `jQuery` objects, not text. If you want the element with class `div` to have the text of both concatenated, use `$(".div").text(x.text() + z.text());`

Answer (score 0):

`$(".2").text(Math.floor((Math.random() * 10)))` is an object, what you want is the text content of the DOM element `$(".2")`.

Something like this:

```js
$(".2").text(Math.floor((Math.random() * 10))),
$(".3").text(Math.floor((Math.random() * 10)));
    
$(".result").text($(".2").text() + $(".3").text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="2"></div>
<div class="3"></div>
<div class="result"></div>
```